# ItemsControl with ItemsWrapGrid in uno platform

Tags: android, xaml, uwp, itemscontrol, uno-platform

I am trying to build an ItemsControl with an auto element arranging ItemsWrapGrid inside (depending on window size). It all works in uwp. But with uno platform ItemsWrapGrid is not fully supported.

I can't set the itemsHeight, itemsWidth or orientation. Is there something like a workaround. Maybe using GridView instead of an ItemControl?

My code:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid ItemsHeight="200" ItemsWidth="300" Orientation="Horizontal">

        </ItemsWrapGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `ItemsWrapGrid` is only supported for `GridView` or `ListView` on Uno Platform, because of [the way that virtualization is handled](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/controls/ListViewBase.html). If you use `GridView` instead of `ItemsControl` it should work.

Note also that if you want to support WebAssembly, `ItemsWrapGrid` isn't supported yet. As a workaround you can use `WrapPanel` there instead. As an example you can look at [the `GridView` style](https://github.com/unoplatform/uado/blob/09ef48700c15610edd8b0fc797aadb530a8feb27/src/Uno.AzureDevOps/Uno.AzureDevOps.Views/Styles/Controls/GridView.xaml#L96) in the UADO reference app.